# Scrolling issues with FlatList when rows are variable height

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using a `FlatList` where each row can be of different height (and may contain a mix of both text and zero or more images from a remote server).

I cannot use `getItemLayout` because I don't know the height of each row (nor the previous ones) to be able to calculate.

The problem I'm facing is that I cannot scroll to the end of the list (it jumps back few rows when I try) and I'm having issues when trying to use `scrollToIndex` (I'm guessing due to the fact I'm missing `getItemLayout`).

I wrote a sample project to demonstrate the problem:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import autobind from 'autobind-decorator';

const items = count => [...Array(count)].map((v, i) => ({
    key: i,
    index: i,
    image: 'https://dummyimage.com/600x' + (((i % 4) + 1) * 50) + '/000/fff',
}));

class RemoteImage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            style: { flex: 1, height: 0 },
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Image.getSize(this.props.src, (width, height) => {
            this.image = { width, height };
            this.onLayout();
        });
    }

    @autobind
    onLayout(event) {
        if (event) {
            this.layout = {
                width: event.nativeEvent.layout.width,
                height: event.nativeEvent.layout.height,
            };
        }
        if (!this.layout || !this.image || !this.image.width)
            return;
        this.setState({
            style: {
                flex: 1,
                height: Math.min(this.image.height,
                    Math.floor(this.layout.width * this.image.height / this.image.width)),
            },
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Image
                onLayout={this.onLayout}
                source={{ uri: this.props.src }}
                style={this.state.style}
                resizeMode='contain'
            />
        );
    }
}

class Row extends Component {
    @autobind
    onLayout({ nativeEvent }) {
        let { index, item, onItemLayout } = this.props;
        let height = Math.max(nativeEvent.layout.height, item.height || 0);
        if (height != item.height)
            onItemLayout(index, { height });
    }

    render() {
        let { index, image } = this.props.item;
        return (
            <View style={[styles.row, this.props.style]}>
                <Text>Header {index}</Text>
                <RemoteImage src = { image } />
                <Text>Footer {index}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default class FlatListTest extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { items: items(50) };
    }

    @autobind
    renderItem({ item, index }) {
        return <Row
        item={item}
        style={index&1 && styles.row_alternate || null}
        onItemLayout={this.onItemLayout}
        />;
    }

    @autobind
    onItemLayout(index, props) {
        let items = [...this.state.items];
        let item = { ...items[index], ...props };
        items[index] = { ...item, key: [item.height, item.index].join('_') };
        this.setState({ items });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList
                    ref={ref => this.list = ref}
                    data={this.state.items}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                />
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    row: {
        padding: 5,
    },
    row_alternate: {
        backgroundColor: '#bbbbbb',
    },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('FlatListTest', () => FlatListTest);
```

Comment: **Gilad Novik**, are you solving this problem ? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Kholiavko Sadly no, I couldn't find a solution yet. Latest RN release still has this problem :(

Comment: @GiladNovik do find the solution?

Answer (score 6):

Use [scrollToOffset()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.56/flatlist#scrolltooffset) instead:

```
    export default class List extends React.PureComponent {

        // Gets the total height of the elements that come before
        // element with passed index
        getOffsetByIndex(index) {
            let offset = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < index; i += 1) {
                const elementLayout = this._layouts[i];
                if (elementLayout && elementLayout.height) {
                    offset += this._layouts[i].height;
                }
            }
            return offset;
        }

        // Gets the comment object and if it is a comment
        // is in the list, then scrolls to it
        scrollToComment(comment) {
            const { list } = this.props;
            const commentIndex = list.findIndex(({ id }) => id === comment.id);
            if (commentIndex !== -1) {
                const offset = this.getOffsetByIndex(commentIndex);
                this._flatList.current.scrollToOffset({ offset, animated: true });
            }
        }

        // Fill the list of objects with element sizes
        addToLayoutsMap(layout, index) {
            this._layouts[index] = layout;
        }

        render() {
            const { list } = this.props;

            return (
                <FlatList
                    data={list}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                        return (
                            <View
                                onLayout={({ nativeEvent: { layout } }) => {
                                    this.addToLayoutsMap(layout, index);
                                }}
                            >
                                <Comment id={item.id} />
                            </View>
                        );
                    }}
                    ref={this._flatList}
                />
            );
        }
    }
```

1. When rendering, I get the size of each element of the list and write it into an array:

`onLayout={({ nativeEvent: { layout } }) => this._layouts[index] = layout}`

2. When it is necessary to scroll the screen to the element, I summarize the heights of all the elements in front of it and get the amount to which to scroll the screen (getOffsetByIndex method).
3. I use the scrollToOffset method:

`this._flatList.current.scrollToOffset({ offset, animated: true });`

(this._flatList is ref of FlatList)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your code. Could you please update your answer to better describe what you are doing?

Comment: This works! this way scroll works from FlatList inside ScrollView. Thank you so much for sharing this snippet @AndreyEremenko

Comment: That works if the item you want to reach and the the ones before it are already been laid out. But it not, what solution do you propose?

Answer (score 1):

So what I think you can do and what you already have the outlets for is to store a collection by the index of the rows layouts `onLayout`. You'll want to store the attributes that's [returned by `getItemLayout`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L92): `{length: number, offset: number, index: number}`.

Then when you implement `getItemLayout` which [passes an index](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L89-L92) you can return the layout that you've stored. This should resolve the issues with `scrollToIndex`. Haven't tested this, but this seems like the right approach.

Comment: this was my idea as well but I haven't been able to get it working. GetItemLayout gets called before onlayout for every row returns and stores a value in the parent component

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `scrollToEnd`?

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltoend

As the documentation states, it may be janky without `getItemLayout` but for me it does work without it

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any way to use `getItemLayout`  when the rows have variable heights , So you can not use `initialScrollIndex` .

But I have a solution that may be a bit slow:
You can use `scrollToIndex` ,  but when your item is rendered . So you need `initialNumToRender` . 
You have to wait for the item to be rendered and after use  `scrollToIndex` so you can not use `scrollToIndex` in `componentDidMount` .

The only solution that comes to my mind is using `scrollToIndex` in `onViewableItemsChanged` . Take note of the example below :
In this example, we want to go to item `this.props.index` as soon as this component is run

```
constructor(props){

        this.goToIndex = true;

    }

render() {
        return (

                <FlatList
                    ref={component => {this.myFlatList = component;}}
                    data={data}
                    renderItem={({item})=>this._renderItem(item)}
                    keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index.toString()}
                    initialNumToRender={this.props.index+1}
                    onViewableItemsChanged={({ viewableItems }) => {
                        if (this.goToIndex){
                            this.goToIndex = false;
                            setTimeout(() => { this.myFlatList.scrollToIndex({index:this.props.index}); }, 10);
                        }
                    }}
                />

        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onScrollToIndexFailed to avoid getItemLayout

```
onScrollToIndexFailed={info => {
            const wait = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
            wait.then(() => {
              refContainer.current?.scrollToIndex({
                index: pinPosition || 0,
                animated: true
              });
            });
          }}
```