# Flatlist items are not showing when height of list is big in Samsung device

Tags: react-native

I'm using nested FlatList.In which inner Flatlist contain services. This list can be of any size. My issue is only with the Samsung device.

Already try this: [Scrolling issues with FlatList when rows are variable height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709142/scrolling-issues-with-flatlist-when-rows-are-variable-height).

```
<FlatList 
    ref={component=>{this.myFlatList = component;}} 
         data={ this.state.employees } 
         extraData={this.state.employees} 
         renderItem={({item ,index}) =>
    <View style={styles.flat_box}>
        .............
        <FlatList 
         data={this.state.employees[index].employee_services} 
         extraData={this.state.employees[index].employee_services} 
         width='90%' marginHorizontal="5%" 
         ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator} 
         renderItem={(value)=>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <Text style={[styles.item, { width: wp( '66') }]} 
                key={ "render_" + value.index}>{value.item?.vendor_service?.service || value.item?.service}</Text>
            </View>
            />
         ............
    </View>
    />
```